# How can I get the IP address of Firebase Database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, microcontroller

I am working on some `microcontroller` device from this device, I have to call Firebase functions to post some `JSON` data but this device is configured like it will take only IP address of database like `http://<ipAddressofCloud>:<portforCloud>/<path>`, not DNS, so now I have to use IP of Firebase database.

I have tried to get IP from the command prompt but for all the databases it is giving the same IP address:

```
Example 1
ping abc.firebaseio.com
output : 12.201.86.45

Example 2
ping xyz.firebaseio.com
output : 12.201.86.45
```

Comment: did you find a way?

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase Database is a shared service and therefore the `firebaseio.com` host is likely to be clustered, so there won't be a single IP address for this.

For instance, my `nslookup` returns different results to yours:

```
Name:       xyz.firebaseio.com
Addresses:  2600:1901:0:94b6::
            35.201.97.85
```

Furthermore, projects are only accessible through their exact `xyz.firebaseio.com` endpoint and do not have their own static IP addresses.

Therefore, you would need to find a way to configure the device to use DNS lookup to translate the domain, rather than specifying an IP address manually.